# Swagger UI Basic Authentication Springfox

Tags: java, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm trying to add custom headers only using Java configuration to Swagger UI (without changing the html file). I'm using springfox, and don't wanna deal with having a separate html file to access swagger ui.

[Swagger UI response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bf4RQ.png)

```
@Bean
SecurityConfiguration security() {
    return new SecurityConfiguration(
            "test-app-client-id",
            "test-app-client-secret",
            "test-app-realm",
            "test-app",
            "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=",
            ApiKeyVehicle.Header,
            "Authorization",
            ",");
}
```

Using this code, I was trying to change

```
--header "api_key: apiKey"
```

into

```
--header "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

or

```
--user username:password
```

but I couldn't do that. The

```
--header "Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="
```

one would change to

```
--header "Authorization: Basic%20dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ%3D"
```

and I'm not sure how to fix that. It would be ideal to get

```
--user username:password
```

to work, but ApiKeyVehicle only has --header, and I don't know if there's a way to change that.

Can anybody give me a hand?

Sorry everything's so messy

Comment: i don't think its possible without changing swagger's index.html

Comment: I think this issue should be fixed in springfox 2.6.0